# Linq query select property list with join

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to get a list in a linq with joins and get all events for specific user.

This is the query I have so far:

```
  var runnerObject = from r in _context.Runners
                               join re in _context.RunnerEvents
                               on r.RunnerId equals re.RunnerId
                               join e in _context.Events
                               on re.EventId equals e.EventId
                               where r.RunnerId == runnerId
                               select new RunnerVM
                               {
                                   RunnerId = r.RunnerId,
                                   FirstName = r.FirstName,
                                   LastName = r.LastName,
                                   UserId = r.UserId,
                                   Events = //get all events in Events table for the runnerId
                               };
```

Events should be all entries from Events table for that runner, based on their id which is joined in the RunnerEvents table. How can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var runnerObject = from r in _context.Runners
                           join re in _context.RunnerEvents
                           on r.RunnerId equals re.RunnerId
                           join e in _context.Events
                           on re.EventId equals e.EventId
                           where r.RunnerId == runnerId
                           select new RunnerVM
                           {
                               RunnerId = r.RunnerId,
                               FirstName = r.FirstName,
                               LastName = r.LastName,
                               UserId = r.UserId,
                               Events = r.Events.Select(e => new Event { }).ToList()
                           };
```